# With Lightning UI enabled - is it possible to stop /aura Operation spam in Developer Console's log panel?

Tags: lightning, developer-console, debug-logs, slowness

When I have Lightning UI Enabled, Open the Dev Console and toggle to the "Logs" tab, my log is spammed with nearly endless `/aura` operations.

[image]

This slows down my general experience in lightning as well, as the dev console I presume is sopping up more resources more regularly to post and read all of those new log entries. Closing dev console returns lightning UI to normal speeds, but it crawls with console open.

I've checked and confirmed that I am NOT listed in the Lightning "Debug Mode Users" list. That list is empty.

**Thus far, I've only found two ways to make this stop:**

1. Turn off ALL debugging using a Log Level where all log types are set to "NONE"

   - (obviously not helpful)
   - starts spamming again as soon as you toggle any **single** log type to anything other than NONE
2. Switch back to Classic UI.

> **Question:** Outside of these, is there an official way to stop my dev console from reporting on `/aura` operations while remaining in
>   lightning UI? It renders Dev Console nearly unusable due to the load
>   it puts on the machine.